# JAVA RX : use @PathParam and application/x-www-form-urlencoded body in the same method

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I've an EJB with a method annotated to expose it as a rest web service.

```
@Path(value = "{group}/grid")
@POST
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public GridResponse<MyObject> getTypeFromGroup(
        @PathParam(value = "group") String group, 
        MultivaluedHashMap<String,String> formParams
) throws BssException;
```

The `MultivaluedHashMap` will contains some dynamic info used by the query and aren't known.
The `PathParam` is used to create a particular filter.

When I call this method i've the following error:

```
12:17:22,847 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type
```

If I remove the `PathParam`, it works.

If I remove the `MultipartHashMap`, it works.

Is it possible to use `@PathParam` and `MultipartHashMap` in the same method?

EDIT:
The client send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request and I can't change it. I want to use the path param to leave all the rest unchanged.

Comment: Try `MultivaluedMap` (the interface) instead of the concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@Consume` type from `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` and move `@PathParam` to end of your method `args`:

```
@Path(value = "{group}/grid")
@POST
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public GridResponse<MyObject> getTypeFromGroup(
        MultivaluedHashMap<String,String> formParams,
        @PathParam(value = "group") String group,
) throws BssException;
```

Comment: Same problem :(

Comment: @DanieleLicitra try replacing `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` to`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

Comment: Thank you, with JSON works, but i can't use it because the client send a x-www-form-urlencoded